# to show that a subset of R is at most countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question says that - "S is a subset of R. C = { x $\in$ R : any open neighborhood of x intersects S at uncountable many points}. Show that S\C is at most countable."

I was trying to show that S\C has no limit point , since a set with no limit point is at most countable.
On the contrary if x be a limit point of S\C then every neighborhood of x contains infinitely many points of S\C. since the points are from S\C every neighborhood of that point contain at most countably many points of S. But from here I'm clue less. Any kind of guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The statement is obviously wrong: take $S = \mathbb{R}$ and $C$ *any* subset with uncountable complement in $S$. Did you copy it down wrong?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: The statement is true: $C$ is the set of points $x$ such that every open nbhd of $x$ has uncountable intersection with $S$, so $S\setminus C$ is the set of $x\in S$ such that $x$ has an open nbhd meeting $S$ in a countable set; that set is necessarily countable, since $\Bbb R$ is secound countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Megha wrote "$C$ is collection of points". I see you filled in "$C$ is **the** collection of points", while Serveas and I filled in "$C$ is **a** collection of points"... A reasonable misunderstanding, I think.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I suspected that that was how you were reading it, but since the result is in fact true under my interpretation and trivial under the other interpretation, I’m reasonably sure that mine was intended.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed. I didn't even notice there was a word missing...

Comment: sorry for the language mistake @AlexKruckman

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

In fact $S\setminus C$ **can** have limit points. For instance, let $S=[0,1]\cup(\Bbb Q\cap[2,3]$; then $C=[0,1]$, so $S\setminus C=\Bbb Q\cap(2,3)$, whose closer is $[2,3]$.

Note that each $x\in S\setminus C$ has an open nbhd that intersects $S$ in only countably many points. Let $x\in S\setminus C$, and let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$ such that $U\cap S$ is countable; then $U\cap S\subseteq S\setminus C$ (why?). Now use the fact that $\Bbb R$ has a countable base to show that $S\setminus C$ is countable.

Answer (score -1):

The statement is false; take $S=\Bbb{R}$ and $C=\varnothing$.

Less vacuous and more general: Take any nonempty open interval $S\subset R$ and any strictly smaller open interval $C\subset S$.

Comment: When $S=\Bbb R$, every open nbhd of every point of $\Bbb R$ has uncountable intersection with $S$, so $C=S$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I do not understand your comment; I think we have interpreted the question differently?

Comment: By definition $C$ is the set $x\in\Bbb R$ such that every open nbhd of $x$ has uncountable intersection with $S$.

Comment: @Servaes See my comment to the question above. It comes down to bad English in the question.